# Config for ubuntu 14.04, eclipse Neon, python 2.7, Django 1.9, Pydev and virtualenv doesn't create src folder

Tags: python, django, eclipse, python-2.7, ubuntu

Coming from PHP, I'm an absolute beginner with Python/Django.
I have successfully installed a virtual environment. So I can see a result with localhost:8000 and localhost:8000/admin. (Standard SQLITE)

The folders lie with user rights in /home/.../django-test. The python environment is in folder django-test/searchem, the first Django instance is django-test/django1.

As I wrote this works.

In eclipse (pydev) I have 2 python interpreters:

- /usr/bin/python2.7 -> called Python 2.7
- /home/XXX/searchem/bin/python2.7  -> called python 2.7 django

For the latter the shown libraries are:

- xxx/searchem/lib/python2.7
- xxx/searchem/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
- /usr/lib/python2.7
- /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i368-linux-gnu
- xxx/searchem/lib/python2.7/site-packages
- /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
- xxx/searchem/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

The built-ins are a lot!
Predefinded, Environment, String Substitution Variables are empty.

Then I create a PyDev Django Project. But no matter where the workspace is definded, or if I chose "Add project directory to the PYTHONPATH" or "create src folder and add it to the PYTHONPATH", the result is either an empty src folder or no src-folder:

[eclipse-pydev-virtual-env-no-src-folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS1kk.png)

So what do I do wrong???

Comment: I recommend `LiClipse` http://www.liclipse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any inconvenience, found now the solution myself! The usual problems as beginner: I did not know about the naming conventions, so I used - instead _.
After finding the error.log from eclipse (I usually use netbeans) I saw the problem. Solution: 2 min, finding the problem: 1 day!

Will be funny the next weeks ;(